# Trying to understand the syntax of this .contain() function

Tags: javascript, callback

the contain function below is written based on .reduce() function:

```
 _.reduce = function(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
  each(collection,function(value){
    accumulator=iterator(accumulator,value);

  });
  return accumulator 
  };
```

Im kinda confused by the syntax here, or is it written logically? why we use if statement first and return 'wasFound' first, before set item===target? isn't if item===target is true, we set wasFound to true?

```
     _.contains = function(collection, target) {
        return _.reduce(collection, function(wasFound, item) {
          if (wasFound) {
            return true;
          }
          return item === target;
        }, false);
      };
```

Comment: It returns `true` there because the first arg signals whether it found a match previously. Did you look at the Underscore documentation? (Or lodash if that's what you're using.)

Answer (score 1):

The first time the `reduce` function makes a match (`return item === target`) it will subsequently return true for all remaining items to be iterated. There is no reason to check if future values match the target because we only care if the collection contains the target at least 1 time. That is why if `wasFound` is true it simply returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You use it like this:

```
_.contains([1,2,3], 2);
//=> true

_.contains([1,2,3], 5);
//=> false
```

It takes a list and an element. It sets `wasFound` to `false` initially and then for each `item` in the `collection` checks: (1) if `wasFound` is `true`, then *some* previous `item` has been identical to `target`, so set `wasFound` to `true` to maintain it, (2) otherwise, set `wasFound` to the value of `item === target`.

Comment: OP is trying to understand the `_.contains` as it uses the matching implementation of `_.reduce`. Using the native `reduce` function goes against what they're trying to understand.

Comment: @MikeC Thanks. I realized that that was the wrong thing to do. Corrected.